# How to anchor an UIView to the bottom of layout (with in-call status bar)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uistatusbar

Created a custom tab bar and while trying to anchor it to the bottom of my UIViewController found that the in-call status bar moves the bottom anchor weirdly.

To demonstrate my problem, I create a fresh iOS project, put an label in the Main.storyboard and constrain it to the view's bottom.

[image]

Then, when I run the project and toggle the in-call status bar, this happens ([label in bottom left corner](https://streamable.com/r1d60))

Searched already 2 days on the internet for an answer, but couldn't find anything which is relatable... I get it that the view gets resized, but I would still expect that my label shouldn't move. So is there a way to disable this choppy resize movement or how does the UITabBarController, with its TabBar, avoid this?

Comment: You're not giving your label a horizontal position, which is why it moves to the left.  The up and down motion is just what iOS is doing.  Bring up Safari in the simulator and toggle the in-call status bar.  You get weird movement there as well.

Comment: @vacawama I intentionally left out the horizontal position to simplify the example. And do you know of any way to disable this? Because the TabBar of UITabBarController doesn't move at all.

Comment: I don't know how to disable that behavior.  Sorry.

Comment: @vacawama No problem mate, thanks for noting the Safari example.